# Edit bone transforms for each key frame to fix mixamo animation

Tags: skeletal-animation, fbx, file-format

I have downloaded FBX animations from Mixamo.com for use in game.

But seems like the "root" skeleton bone does not have translations in Z axis; which makes animations like climbing a ladder or ledge unusable in game engine.

The animation file does not have any mesh data and has just one animation layer.

So I am trying to write a small utility application using **FBX SDK 2017.1** that will:

1. Read an FBX file that I got from Mixamo.com
2. For each keyframe translate the root skeleton bone to always maintain an offset in Z direction from pelvis bone
3. The above step will make the skeleton hierarchy jump due to root bone being translated. So in this step I want to recursively set pelvis bone at an offset for each key frame

   4. Export the edited scene into an FBX file

Here's a code snippet

```
for (int keyIndex = numKeys-1; keyIndex >= 0; keyIndex--)
    {
        // For each key frame fix the Z transform for ROOT bone
        // Similar loop for PELVIS bone
        FbxAnimCurveKey pRootAnimKey = pRootAnimCurve->KeyGet(keyIndex);

        pRootAnimCurve->KeyModifyBegin();
            float originalValue = pRootAnimKey.GetValue();  // for debugging purposes
            float fixValue = 0.0f;
            FbxAnimCurve *pPelvisAnimCurve = pPelvisBone->LclTranslation.GetCurve(pAnimLayer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Z);
            if (pPelvisAnimCurve != NULL) {
                FbxAnimCurveKey pPelvisAnimKey = pPelvisAnimCurve->KeyGet(animKeyIndex);
                // this "delta" can be a +ve or -ve value calculated from skeleton's Rest/T-pose
                fixValue = pPelvisAnimKey.GetValue() + delta;

                pAnimCurve->KeySetValue(keyIndex, fixValue);
            }

        pAnimCurve->KeyModifyEnd();
    }
```

[image: Here's what my problem look like]

I want the root bone to stay in between legs at an offset from pelvis bone, just as it is in rest T-pose.

Issue is that the exported file does have **root** bone follow **pelvis** bone's Z translation but after second loop is run and the file is exported my pelvis bone does not seem to follow **root** bone.
I have tried doing once conversion at a time i.e.

1. BUGGY animation -> FBX with root following **pelvis** bone
2. (1) -> pelvis following **root** bone

any ideas how to fix this?

There are ways to download mixamo animations without **root** bone i.e. **pelvis** is the root bone in that case and manually edit animation in Autodesk Maya to make it work. But I have 2400+ animations that needs to be fixed, so that would be a lot time consuming.